# Import soap webservice xml to node with Feeds?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, feeds

I have a soap web service which requires authentication to access its various function. I want to call one function of this web service and import that XML to node in Drupal with [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module.

I am not finding any example of authentication from the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have no access to change the feed provider.

There are couple of additional contributed modules which handle different types of authentication for the feeds module.

This handles regular http authentication, which is more likely with soap:
https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_httpfetcher_aa

and this one is for oauth which ia also possible with soap:
https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_oauth

Comment: My webservice url is like
https://example-webservice.com/ws.asmx 
I want to call a function getUserList which takes one argument 'type' and returns xml ( there are several function in web service ).
I tried above module with no success because I do not see any place to add argument for function.

Comment: Are you managing to authenticate now? It sounds like you may have a problem with your webservice more than drupal. What errors are you getting when you conect to the webservice.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_soap                 This module seems more appropriate for my use case but it is not available for drupal 7

Comment: [https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient_feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient_feeds) This may do it